# Get Google Maps Key for Android using new Google Cloud Console

Tags: android, google-maps

I couldn't find the way to get the maps key on the new Google Cloud Console. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#create_an_api_project_in_the_google_apis_console) still shows how to proceed in the old way.
Anybody is having the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that getting a new google map key, just follow the steps:
1. create a new project if don't have one
2. select "APIs & auth" on the left (or you can choose "go back" in the reminder ribbon)
[image]
3. select "registered apps"
[image]
4. click on button "register app" to add create a new key
[image]
5. or you can check the existing key of the apps in the list in step 4

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console)
2. Create a new project or go to the existing one
3. Click on Registered Apps
4. Create a new app or select an existing Android one
5. Click on Android Key, you will get the key

You will find more informations on [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key)